# How to get a certain sequence of self-signature on python3?

Tags: android, python-3.x, rsa, pkcs#7, asn.1

I need to get the python3 from the key signature raw data from the second sequence. I can not say how it is exactly called. This is part of the public key that is signed by the APK package. Android type [Signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/Signature.html)

In C #, I just write.

```
var certfile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath (file);
var Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile (certfile);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (v + "RSA_PUBLIC_DATE.RSA", Cert.GetRawCertData ());
```

Can't do the same thing on python3. I tried different libraries. Many people know this type of key. But do not work with primitives.

[link original saignatures](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#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-r3I1uk6qV27_B6N07xxyW2n7HPjoakaeL1SddMIDVqxW0S2ZvKNhhjccJ3uZfW7brizA8YHdCWiBCSi9zZ1fH6nm5PI3ss1_HxyLO_VE4-c92Q_bHiS99mLL2QKwD8maBbfXj2iUaScwE2kW-gPWlr9WdwyfhF1aB3FlzQdypXUO5RYHoV_7U1mtNsTb0xsteL6Wd6XBqPqZ9HApfa0_KgEXhLti7vYfvAzY7sSSw-fkQSPYAF_aVUopxXTOfgBfTC_kQZTXYxV3RK5yahnnnWVLWcCYYH9RYUg9LYHrjMcoj2vqZSA6JsUQzJ2MO2L5YAh8vAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAHezD7MWvq59v0KfAxtLg6MnPGQ1X8aaMjG71aVLB6BR4VO_bmclspB97V-ztHwkP_Nj9T4F9fVaimfxEkv6hy_eakw2rzuRuElw4iYs5lKFhH5q-84TtWRB612HEX74MguwGWG6aD1T7tB9VFwPLTIdWIenIfXd9Kk3iLKVDn6lRXTM66YHTEGH976aHAqYnNdeo9hfgfPQe2zAe3UTNNArV-NRLsMZ--i1GYxspuZ4f2zi7N23fuqTiNeQWIhwo0QE_b-dpjnRj2w9HXHz1v0uRkU7fOg7mP26iJ3hcxbb_4NlOS-nqnNgjRQsLS6JY7nlIQ8jJUYivzgVcrmV3lsxggHLMIIBxwIBATCBozCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxEzARBgNVBAgTClBldGVyc2J1cmcxGDAWBgNVBAcTD1NhaW50UGV0ZXJzYnVyZzETMBEGA1UEChMKVW5pdmVyc2l0eTERMA8GA1UECxMITWlsa3lXYXkxDTALBgNVBAMTBEFsZXgxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWx1Y2VtdXNAZ21haWwuY29tAgkA7F7t09baBPcwCQYFKw4DAhoFADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAQBtXrewl2XTpYHxuQ9YH1mvAJRGHv_KgsG3Fuy9sdVYuobeWGCor-NYlzN_g7MQHaUl8yl7hoWYHSWe3HXWeNy4zn35FxP_QAkFRIw5UMGI0tjUa0W3eXYNhHVOHsbG0OXUakbbHJxhHYdDMk9ugkgKt2ce6gcR3mSOuZiSsCac5qR9Y4_eosxOQPEr-rKQQMQMJVRWN6ylAc4L9eyMZnOUyaUq2YJX1O2Bd_V9_f5UtBW5g2VBmHy6y9TS619DndrMMnMmSE6Odpp-80y7lrqCFABZklYHI0bBnZqCRcnirqNI0ENO_sfrZe7iWDD7WvbM-_BXBCxc_FHAAJaKebr0)

[link sequnce im want get](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#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_wejdO8ccltp-xz46GpGni9UnXTCA1asVtEtmbyjYYY3HCd7mX1u264swPGB3QlogQkovc2dXx-p5uTyN7LNfx8cizv1ROPnPdkP2x4kvfZiy9kCsA_JmgW3149olGknMBNpFvoD1pa_VncMn4RdWgdxZc0HcqV1DuUWB6Ff-1NZrTbE29MbLXi-lnelwaj6mfRwKX2tPyoBF4S7Yu72H7wM2O7EksPn5EEj2ABf2lVKKcV0zn4AX0wv5EGU12MVd0SucmoZ551lS1nAmGB_UWFIPS2B64zHKI9r6mUgOibFEMydjDti-WAIfLwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQB3sw-zFr6ufb9CnwMbS4OjJzxkNV_GmjIxu9WlSwegUeFTv25nJbKQfe1fs7R8JD_zY_U-BfX1Wopn8RJL-ocv3mpMNq87kbhJcOImLOZShYR-avvOE7VkQetdhxF--DILsBlhumg9U-7QfVRcDy0yHViHpyH13fSpN4iylQ5-pUV0zOumB0xBh_e-mhwKmJzXXqPYX4Hz0HtswHt1EzTQK1fjUS7DGfvotRmMbKbmeH9s4uzdt37qk4jXkFiIcKNEBP2_naY50Y9sPR1x89b9LkZFO3zoO5j9uoid4XMW2_-DZTkvp6pzYI0ULC0uiWO55SEPIyVGIr84FXK5ld5b)

Comment: Did you try [this](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) fine library? Also, you know there is a [Russian language stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) that you might find easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I watched this library.  Unfortunately, there is no simple solution.  It's easier for me to use the Python DotNet library.